# Visual Studio, TFS and file system links

Tags: visual-studio-2013, symlink

My Visual Studio projects are located in C:\Users\MyName\ProjectName.

To make life easier (I thought), I created a file system link in the root called TFS.
(i.e. `C:\TFS` points to `C:\Users\MyName\Projects`)

I always open my projects from the link (i.e. C:\Tfs\ProjectName\ProjectName.sln) and my TFS local paths uses the link.

This work fine most of the time but someVisual Studio and TFS think files are in C:\Users\MyName...
i.e. If I look at the properties of projects in a solution, one can be in C:\Tfs and another in C:\Users. I have verified that there are no absolute paths in any solution or project files.

When this happen and I add a new file to a project TFS becomes a real mess. TFS thinks the new file is in C:\Users and is not versions controlled but at the same time there is a file with the same name in the C:\TFS folder so I need to resolve a conflict. I can resolve the conflict but TFS starts versioning the C:\Users file. i.e. the local folder for the project is C:\TFS... but according to TFS (and pending changes) the new files live in C:\Users.

I have not found a way to change the local name of file, only a folder.

Is there a way to resolve this or should I just get rid of the link?
(It works slightly better with a TFS local workspace but the problem is still there)

Comment: Stop using the links in this way, it will confuse the hell out of the workspace configuration and Visual Studio as you are encountering. Instead, just map your project to `c:\tfs`

Comment: @jessehouwing, you make it sound like this is common knowledge. I have used the same setup with mercurial for years and symbolic links has been in common use on windows since Vista. What makes VS/TFS randomly following links?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### <tl;dr>

Symlinks are funny things and because TFVC stores binding information outside of the source control folder, it may get very confused when your repository is stored in or includes them.

### Details

Opposed to Git, Mercurial and Subversion, TFVC doesn't just keep the binding of disk to repository in a subfolder of the repository (in case of a server workspace it doesn't keep this data on disk with the repository at all). It also stores it in a number of other places, namely the TFS server and your user profile.

When you look at a subversion or git repository you'll find the `.svn` or `.git` folders which contain the information of which folders on disk map to the repository.

With TFVC this information is not only stored on disk (in case of Local workspaces), but also on the server (machine name, server path, local path) and in your user profile (under `AppData\Local\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\`). These configurations store the full paths and these are used to see if a file is under version control or not. The reason why Local workspaces improve things, is because they add the `tf$` folder with some of the binding information.

Since a workspace mapping can map a folder in your repository only to one folder on disk, the use of symlinks confuses the TFVC client. You might consider this a bug, since Microsoft should be able to resolve the link (depending on the link type), but Visual Studio assumes you are not using links. Other reasons why this (potentially) confuses Visual Studio is that file size and other attribute changes are not always signaled in case links are used (date changed and file size may not be notified until Visual Studio is told to refresh the solution). The Read-Only bit (which TFVC uses in case of server workspaces) also has special behavior in case links are used and may cause issues of undetected checkouts.

More on [the strange edge cases caused by links, can be found here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I'm not sure why you'd want to use a link in this case, the sources are already stored in TFS, so a backup of your profile doesn't add much and only makes you system slower in case you have a roaming profile. Plus, workspaces are machine bound and should never "move between machines" magically anyway.

You can submit a suggestion on the [Visual Studio User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio), or file a bug on [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) if you want to see this behavior changed, but to solve your problem, use normal folders and map your files to a unique location.

Just keep in mind, very few applications in Windows are built to handle Symlinks, and those that are  may cause strange behaviors. Windows explorer (file open dialogs and drag&drop) may provide the original file location, instead of the link location for certain actions and changes to attributes in one location may not be visible in the linked location.

As you can see here, systems will be able to see the difference between symlinks and real directories, and thus may act on that knowledge:

[image]

Comment: Ok, thank you for your thorough answer. I understand TFS a bit better now and since I also discovered that it is possible to actually lose work on commit I will remove the link. Still don't understand why VS sometimes follow the link and sometimes not. (e.g. found out that projects in the solution folder get the C.\Tfs path but projects in other folders get the C.\Users path even if both got relative paths in the solutions file).

Comment: I think it's still worth a Connect ticket. But I guess they'll close it with a: works as designed. Not many people know that symlinks exist even fewer use them.